# How to access more tags in single method using htmlagilitypack in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, web-crawler, html-agility-pack

I am designing a program to crawl the web page thenextweb.com for its posts (links, post content, image, date, author etc.)

The html for its one post is as :

```
<div class="media-data">

                     <h4><a href="http://thenextweb.com/mobile/2012/01/05/nokia-reportedly-to-appoint-f-secure-founder-risto-siilasmaa-as-new-chairman/">Nokia to Name Risto Siilasmaa as New Chairman</a></h4>
                     <p class="article-meta"><a href="http://thenextweb.com/mobile/">TNW Mobile</a> &#8226; <a href="http://thenextweb.com/author/matt/" title="Posts by Matt Brian" rel="author">Matt Brian</a>  &#8226; <span class="date" title="1325748846">January 5, 2012</span></a></p>

                     <p>Nokia is reportedly planning to nominate and name Risto Siilasmaa, founder of Finnish anti-virus and computer security F-Secure, as its new chairman by the end of the month, Finland&#8217;s Helsingin Sanomat reports&#8230;</p>
                 </div>
```

This is the html for next 15 posts on home page.
For accessing its content i have used :

```
  var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
  var document = webGet.Load(url);
 var infos = from info in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class ='media-data']//h4//a")
                        select new
                        {
                            LinkURL = info.Attributes["href"].Value,
                            Text = info.InnerText
                        };

            lvLinks.DataSource = infos;
            lvLinks.DataBind();
```

and to access the information of Authors, date etc i used :

```
 var infos = from info in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class ='media-data']//p[@rel = 'author']")
                        select new
                        {
                           Author = info.InnerText
                        };

            lvLinks.DataSource = infos;
            lvLinks.DataBind();
```

I have used list view control to show the data on ASP page as `<li> <%# Eval("Text") %>  - <%# Eval("LinkUrl") %> </li>`

But i want a way so that i can access all of them in one go...No need to write different code for **links, content** and other for **author, date** etc.

Can there be a method so that i can write and retrieve information under `<div class="media-data">... </div>`tags for any node i want and store it ?

Please suggest this as it is very important to attach the authors, date information with the post link itself. I am not able to do that.

Thanks

Comment: Any reason not to use the provided All Stories / Top Stories RSS feeds?

Comment: There are some cutomization i need to do on all the stories...That's why i need to fetch them from the web page only.

Answer (score 0):

You could select nodes of type `<div class="media-data">` first, and then select all the necessary sub-nodes inside it:

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class ='media-data']")
    .Select(div => new
    {
        Link = div.SelectSingleNode("h4/a"),
        Author = div.SelectSingleNode("//*[@rel='author']"),
        Date = div.SelectSingleNode("//*[@class='date']"),
        Content = div.SelectSingleNode("p[last()]")
    }).Select(data => new
    {
        LinkURL = data.Link.Attributes["href"].Value,
        Text = data.Link.InnerText,
        Author = data.Author.InnerText,
        Date = DateTime.Parse(data.Date.InnerText),
        Content = data.Content.InnerHtml
    });
```